# Add an option to email all responses

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, email

The [current email notification system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/) doesn't do what many people think it does to judge from emails sent to the community manager team.  The rule that's a bit tricky is:

> Bear in mind that **we will only email you if you have not checked your global inbox in that time interval**. Meaning, if you select the default of “daily”, and you don’t click to expand your global inbox on *any Stack Exchange site* for a full 24 hour period...you'll then get an email delivered to you with the contents of your global inbox. And if you don't check for *another 24* hours, you will get another email, and so forth.

What trips people up is that they sign up for email every 3 hours and they never see any emails at all.  Having used sites that use less sophisticated email notifications (Facebook, Trello, LinkedIn, etc.) I really appreciate the utility of the Stack Exchange email notification.  But it doesn't fit many people's mental model of the feature.  Plus, some people legitimately want copies of all of their responses to file away for future reference.  For someone who only gets a handful of comments, it wouldn't really even be that many emails.